POSIX or Linux-specific method of connecting a readable file descriptor to a writable file descriptor?
I've got a file descriptor, which might've come from a socket, a pipe, or an actual file, that can be read from. I've got another file descriptor (again, might represent a socket or an actual file) which can be written to. I need to pass data from one to the other, as rapidly as possible.
Currently, I know of no way to do this except picking an arbitrary buffer size, reading into it from the first descriptor, and then writing it to the second descriptor (which may require a loop if it can't write everything that was read in one go). I would like, instead, to be able to say "read from this file descriptor and put the data directly into that file descriptor, without an intermediate buffer"--or, better yet, "read from this file descriptor until it hits EOF, and put it all directly into that file descriptor, as quickly as possible." It seems to me that there ought to be a way to do this without detouring through user space, and paying for copying the data out of kernel buffers and then back into kernel buffers again, but I can't find any such way, and every phrase I've come up with to google for it just leads me to stuff about UNIX shell pipes. Is there a way to do it, or am I just stuck?

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html

@DanielA.White EINVAL Either fd_in or fd_out is not a regular file.

There are some Linux-specific systen calls like sendfile or copy_file_range or splice, but none of them work with all types of files. You may want to try all of them in order, and if all fail, fall back to normal read-write userspace copying.

You might be able to use a memory mapped file too
